# Prototype submit event handling on newly inserted form

Tags: javascript, events, prototype

I have a number of clickable images / buttons on a page that have the following( using Prototype.js).

```
    $$( '.lbrchk' ).each( function ( name ) {
        name.observe( 'click' , function ( ev ) {
          var form = new Element( 'form',
                                    {
                                      method: 'post',
                                      action: 'url',
                                    });

            form.insert(new Element( 'input',
                                      {
                                        name: 'user',
                                        value: $(this).down( "input[name=user]" ).value,
                                        type: 'hidden'
                                      }));

            form.insert(new Element( 'input',
                                      {
                                        name: 'pin',
                                        value: '',
                                        type: 'password'
                                      }));

            form.insert(new Element( 'input',
                                      {
                                        type: 'submit',
                                        value: 'Submit',
                                       'class': 'processing'
                                      }));

            $('modal-content').insert(form); 
            $('modal').show();
            $('modal-content').down("input[name=user]").focus();

        });
    });
```

and others that have this.

```
$$( '.lbrinq' ).each( function ( name ) {
    name.observe( 'click' , function ( ev ) {
        var form = new Element( 'form',
                                {
                                  method: 'post',
                                  action: 'url'
                                });

            form.insert(new Element( 'input',
                                  {
                                    name: 'document',
                                    value: $(this).down("input[name=document]").value,
                                    type: 'hidden'
                                  }));

             $(document.body).insert(form);
             form.submit(); 

    });
});
```

Both are similar but one creates a modal form asking for user input before submitting, the other creates the form elements and submits the form pragmatically when the button/image is clicked.

I need to add a submit event handler to allow only one form submission.  Since these forms are created dynamically everything I'm trying is failing in one way or another.

I've Tried changing

```
    var form = new Element( 'form',
                            {
                              method: 'post',
                              action: 'url'
                            });
```

to

```
    var form = new Element( 'form',
                            {
                              method: 'post',
                              action: 'url',
                              onsubmit: 'alert("hi");return false;'
                      //also  onsubmit: function(){ alert("hi" ); }

                            });
```

I've also tried adding a submit listener to the document

```
 document.observe( 'submit', function( e, el ) {

    if ( el = e.findElement( 'form' ) ) {

          // Disable  all submit buttons
          $$( 'input[type="submit"]' ).invoke( 'disable' );         

          // If no previous submissions detected go ahead
            if( subck == 0){
              // show loading graphic to user
              $('processing_gif').show();

                  subck = 1;
                 return true;  // jump out of logic to continue normal operation
            } else { // Previous submission detected

              // Stop right here to prevent multiple submissions.
                e.stop();       
        }
    }
  });
```

Which works in firefox but not in IE 8/9.

does anyone have any suggestion on how to handle 'submit' events on dynamicly created forms?

Comment: If you are adding elements to the DOM there will be no events hooked up to the new elements -- you have to attach them AFTER they're inserted int othe DOM.

Comment: `form.observe( "submit", function() { alert("hi");});` 
after  `$(document.body).insert(form);`  is not working but maybe my issue is how i'm referencing the element.